# C# Active Directory Service Integration Practices Question?

Tags: c#, active-directory

I have enabled active directory authentication in my desktop application, my question is what happens if the AD server is down? Should I just throw the exception handled and say "Sorry ad is down cannot authenticate you right now , check with system administrator ?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, and give them a secondary login option if possible/applicable.

Kind of like how SQL server works.  You can login using Windows authentication, or SQL authentication.  Since a lot of the Windows authentication being done would be done through a domain, and as such it would use Active Directory, if AD was down, they'd be able to login using SQL server authentication (assuming both are allowed, and sorry for going slightly off topic for example's sake)

Comment: I think I could do that in my app ! but the usecase for the app password would be trick, I would have to advice the user to create a "app" only password...